# Getting Apache Substitute for multipart/mixed to work

Tags: apache, http, reverse-proxy, substitution

I have created an employee portal for the company I work for but am having an issue on rewriting my Internal Hostname with the Portal's Hostname for a Content-Type of "multipart/mixed".

Below is the content I am trying to replace.

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=294D9B061EABA796BC8484AAC5CB4BB90
dataserviceversion: 2.0
Content-Length: 604
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Sun, 16 Sep 2018 16:03:06 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-Akamai-Staging: ESSL

--294D9B061EABA796BC8484AAC5CB4BB90
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Length: 436
content-transfer-encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 339
dataserviceversion: 2.0

{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"id":"https://www.internalhostname.abc/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZABC_MY_PAYSTUBS_SRV/ConcurrentEmploymentSet('anotherValue')","uri":"https://www.internalhostname.abc/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZABC_MY_PAYSTUBS_SRV/ConcurrentEmploymentSet('anotherValue')","type":"ZABC_MY_PAYSTUBS_SRV.ConcurrentEmployment"},"Pernr":"anotherValue","AssignmentText":""}]}}
--294D9B061EABA796BC8484AAC5CB4BB90--
```

I am using the Apache HTTP 2.4.  And am familiar with the Substitute command.
I have a section:

```
<Location "/sap">
SetOutputFilter INFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/http
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/json
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE multipart/mixed
Substitute 's|www.internalhostname.abc|portal.abc.com|ni'
</Location>
```